# Product probability

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider a space of probability $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\lambda)$. Consider the measurable space $(\Omega\times\mathbb{R},\mathcal{F}\otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),P\otimes \lambda)$.

Given $A$ measurable in $\mathcal{F}\otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ with $P\otimes\lambda (A)>0$, is it true that there exists $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $B\in\mathcal{F}$ with $P(B)>0$ such that $B\times\{x\}\subset A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Define $A_x:=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid \langle\omega,x\rangle\in A\}$ so that $A_x\times\{x\}\subseteq A$ for $x\in\mathbb R$.

Then $A_x\in\mathcal F$ for each $x\in\mathbb R$.

This can be proved by showing that the collection $\{A\subseteq\Omega\times\mathbb R\mid A_x\in\mathcal F\text{ for every }x\in\mathbb R\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and contains the collection $\{F\times B\mid F\in\mathcal F, B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\}$.

We have:

$$\int P(A_x)\lambda(dx)=\int\int1_A(\omega,x)P(d\omega)\lambda(dx)=(P\otimes\lambda)(A)>0$$

This implies that $P(A_x)>0$ for some $x$.